# jQuery scrollTop animation looping issue

Tags: jquery, html, animation, scrolltop

I'm not very savvy when it comes to using jQuery and I'm working on a project that involves animating a section within a phone so it scrolls down demonstrating the contents inside the phone. I have 2 phones, side by side, that animate. The way it works is the left will scroll, pause, and then the one on the right scrolls and then pauses. They will do this until they reach the end. They also have a ball icon that animates with it.

I got it to work, but the scope of the project is that the scroll animation within the phones will animate when a user scrolls to that section on the page. When I tried to get that to work, the animations loop back up to the top which I don't want them to do. I don't know what's causing this issue.

If anyone can be of any help, I'll really appreciate it. I apologize in advance for my poorly written jQuery. If there are better ways to write the animation, I'll modify it for sure.

This is the original jQuery that worked for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/qxwKL/

```
$(function(){
    $(".portrait .mobile-container").animate({ scrollTop: 560 }, 1200).delay(3000).animate({ scrollTop: 1200 }, 1200);  
    $(".portrait .ball").animate({ top: 720 }, 1200, "linear").delay(3000).animate({ top: 1280 }, 1200, "linear");  

    $(".landscape .mobile-container").delay(2000).animate({ scrollTop: 900 }, 1500).delay(3000).animate({ scrollTop: 1300 }, 1500);  
    $(".landscape .ball").delay(2000).animate({ top: 1000 }, 1300, "linear").delay(3000).animate({ top: 1300 }, 1300, "linear");   
});
```

This is the one I'm having issues with. You'll need to scroll to the section with the phones to trigger the animation to start:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gsk4n/3/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.mobile-device').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+900) {
            $('.portrait-contain', this).delay(1000).animate({ scrollTop: 560 }, 1000).delay(3000).animate({ scrollTop: 1590 }, 1000);
            $('.portrait-contain .ball', this).delay(1000).animate({ top: 720 }, 1000, "linear").delay(3000).animate({ top: 1700 }, 1000, "linear");                    

            $('.landscape-contain', this).delay(3000).animate({ scrollTop: 590 }, 1000).delay(3000).animate({ scrollTop: 1200 }, 1000);
            $('.landscape-contain .ball', this).delay(3000).animate({ top: 650 }, 1000, "linear");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You want the animation to start only when your phone is visible, right?

Comment: Yes, the animation starts when you scroll down to the phones. It should only start when a user scrolls to the section with the 2 phones and the animation shouldn't repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My name is Saucier (: It's in one of your paragraphs

But as for your question, I was able to remedy the situation using a couple tricks. The first is I didn't start the animation until `imagePos <= topOfWindow`, which means the content section for the phones must be fully visible. If you want to change this so it happens sooner, subtract from `imagePos`

The second thing I changed is where your main problem lied. Your animations were firing any time the window was scrolled after the point was reached. To fix the situation, I added a boolean named `hasAnimated` to keep track of whether or not the animation events have fired and put all of your animations inside of an if statement relying on that boolean to be false.

```
if(!hasAnimated) {
    ... All of your animations ...
}
```

The next thing I added was

```
if($(this) == $('.mobile-device:last')) {
    hasAnimated = true;
}
```

which makes your animations not fire more than once (the if is true once the animations for the last element have been applied)

I also added a

```
else {
    hasAnimated = false;
}
```

after the main if statement to reset the animation if the user scrolls back up. If you don't want this functionality and want the animation to only run once regardless, remove this

Lastly, I added a

```
.stop(true,true)
.animate({ scrollTop: 100 }, 1000) //  I used `scrollTop: 0` for the containers
```

To each animation sequence in order to reset the animation before running it again. You may want to change this to happen when the user scrolls above the animation point, I just put it here for ease of coding to show you you could

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Gsk4n/5/) of it all together (:

Comment: Hi Saucier, thank you so much for your help and such a detailed response! :) It might take me some time to understand everything you did, but I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: @user933061 No problem! If you find an answer acceptable, you can click the check mark next to it to mark it as correct. This gives both the answer-er and the OP (original poster - you) reputation for doing so

Comment: @Sorry Saucier. I have been really busy and didn't get a chance to apply the code you helped me with. I wanted to answer it when I did apply it to make sure I didn't have any more questions on it. I'll mark it as answered now.

Comment: @user933061 It's quite okay (: you might go back to a couple of you older questions and do the same